# Fetching data using vercel-kv and next.js

Tags: typescript, next.js, vercel

I have loaded data to my vercel KV (redis) db, using

```
import { kv } from "@vercel/kv";
...
await kv.set("cabins", data)
```

The data has been properly imported to my database, which can be confirmed by using `get cabins` in the CLI on vercel's website, or by running `await kv.get("cabins")` in a script locally.

I want to read this data from an api `route.ts` in my next.js 14 application.

```
// src/app/api/getCabins/route.ts

import { kv } from "@vercel/kv";

...

async function getCabinsFromKV(): Promise<CabinFromKV[]> {
  const cabins = await kv.get("cabins");
  console.log(cabins);
  console.log("PRINTING FROM GETCABINSFROMKV");
  return cabins
}

...

export async function GET() {
  try {
const cabins = await getCabinsFromKV();
...
} catch {...}
```

The print above always gives me `null`, during my `npm run build` and also when i try to run the project locally.

I'm calling this API from a client-side component, inside a `useEffect`:

```
// src/components/heatmap/Heatmap.tsx
“use client”

const Heatmap: React.FC = () = {
  const [cabins, setCabins] = useState<CabinDetails[]>([]);

  ...

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const response = await fetch("/api/getCabins", {
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      });
      const { cabins } = await response.json();
      setCabins(cabins);
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);
...
}
```

Vercel's deployment works well, except for this page which gives: 
`Application error: a client-side exception has occurred (see the browser console for more information).`

Finally, here is my `page.tsx`:

```
// src/app/heatmap/page.tsx    

import Heatmap from "@/components/heatmap/Heatmap";

const Page = async ({}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Heatmap />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Page;
```

I have tried

1. `fetch("/api/getCabins")` directly from `page.tsx`-file, but that gives me an invalid URL error.
2. defining `getCabins()`-function in `page.tsx` with the `'use server'` decorator and then passing that to `Heatmap.tsx`, that doesn't work either.